# Additional items in the VBE Insert Menu

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a couple of extra items in my VBE insert menu.

Does anyone know what they are and how to use them?

[image: VBE Snip]

Comment: A module is a place to write code not associated with particular objects (e.g. the worksheet or workbook) and it won't have built-in object events (e.g. worksheet activate) - a class is a code module that needs to be instantiated first, like a blueprint of an object that can be instanced as many times as you like. You can just google more on this stuff, there are hundreds of entries.

Comment: Which 2 items do you consider 'extra' - the ones greyed out? Have you done any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of these menu items inserts a new code module and adds it to your active project. They vary according to the type of module inserted:

**Module** - Inserts a new module containing only procedure, type, and data declarations and definitions where module-level declarations and definitions are public by default.

**Class Module** - Creates a new class module.  This code defines a class, including its property and method definitions.

**Microsoft Forms 2.0 Form** - Inserts a 2.0 Form, a class that renders an interactive user interface.  Version 2.0 includes properties that were not present in earlier versions.

**Addin Class Module** - Inserts a new Addin class module which is a class module for extending the editor environment itself.